# Django CORS With jQuery Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm developing a python web application using Django. I need to call this web app in my JQuery client. The first few calls always succeeded but after this, Django start to ban the request and show the CORS origin problem. I added django-cors-headers Django application but still the same problem.
JQuery Ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: targetUrl,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: ajaxInputData,
    success: function (data) {
         console.log(ajaxInputData.UserAction + data + " Reply received successfully");
        /*Before calling successCallback you can any shared code here independent on the reply returned for each request*/
        successCallback(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(ajaxInputData.UserAction + "error ya baba Reply received with failure " + xhr.toString());
        /*Before calling successCallback you can any shared code here independent on the reply returned for each request*/
        if (typeof errorCallback != undefined)
            errorCallback(xhr);
    }
```

});

Django's Settings file:

```
"""
Django settings for Clerk_Django project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import posixpath

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


#Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
#See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

#SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#########################################'

#SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'app',
'rest_framework',
'Clerk_Django',
'Clerk_Django.Engine',
'Clerk_Django.Analysis',
'Clerk_Django.Measurement',
'Clerk_Django.Selection',
# Add your apps here to enable them
'django.contrib.admin',
'corsheaders',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

#'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
#'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Clerk_Django.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
# Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
# or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
'FORM_METHOD_OVERRIDE': None,
'FORM_CONTENT_OVERRIDE': None,
'FORM_CONTENTTYPE_OVERRIDE': None,
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
]
}


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Clerk_Django.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}

#CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
#    'http://localhost',
#    '127.0.0.1'
#)

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS'
)


CORS_PREFLIGHT_MAX_AGE = 86400
#CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'x-requested-with',
    'content-type',
    'accept',
    'origin',
    'authorization',
    'x-csrftoken'
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

USE_ETAGS = True

#CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))
```

Main App urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
# Examples:
url(r'^$', app.views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^contact$', app.views.contact, name='contact'),
url(r'^about', app.views.about, name='about'),
url(r'^engine/',include('Clerk_Django.Engine.urls') ),
# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
 #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',  namespace='rest_framework')),
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Engine urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
# Examples:
url(r'^start$', views.startAssessment, name='StartAssessment'),
url(r'^getQuestion$', views.getQuestion, name='GetQuestion'),
url(r'^submitAnswer$', views.submitAnswer, name='SubmitAnswer'),
url(r'^getFinalResult$', views.getFinalResult, name='GetFinalResult'),
url(r'^login$', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^getStatistics$', views.getStatistics, name='getStatistics'),
url(r'^createVacancy$', views.createVacancy, name='createVacancy'),
url(r'^getCompanySkills', views.getCompanySkills, name='getCompanySkills'),
url(r'^editVacancy', views.editVacancy, name='editVacancy'),
url(r'^getVacancy$', views.getVacancy, name='getVacancy'),
url(r'^getVacancies$', views.getVacancies, name='getVacancies'),
url(r'^getVacanciesBrief$', views.getVacanciesBrief, name='getVacanciesBrief'),
url(r'^getApplicants$', views.getApplicants, name='getApplicants'),
url(r'^getApplicant$', views.getApplicant, name='getApplicant'),
url(r'^SubmitApplicant$', views.SubmitApplicant, name='SubmitApplicant')
]
```

Requested View:

```
def login(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    variables =  request.POST
elif request.method == "GET":
    variables =  request.GET

username = variables.get("email", "")
password = variables.get("password", "")
try:

    result = DBCommands.AuthenticateUser(username,password)
    if len(result) > 0:
        obj = Assessment([1])
        jsonResponse = __getJSONResponse(20,"succeeded",result,None)
        return HttpResponse(jsonResponse)
    else:
        jsonResponse = __getJSONResponse(21,"error","Not authenticated",None)
        return HttpResponse(jsonResponse, status = 21)
except:
    jsonResponse = __getJSONResponse(21,"error","error while authenticating user",None)
    return HttpResponse(jsonResponse, status = 21)
```

Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.4\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
>       self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.4\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in **call**
>       return self.application(environ, start_response)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.4\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 185, in **call**
>       start_response(force_str(status), response_headers)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.4\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 230, in start_response
>       assert status[3]==" ", "Status message must have a space after code"
>   AssertionError: Status message must have a space after code
>   [12/Jun/2016 20:13:21] "POST /engine/getVacancy HTTP/1.1" 500 59

XMLHttpResponse:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/engine/getCompanySkills. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Please can anyone tells me what is the problem?

Comment: post the traceback + the view you want to send the ajax to + url conf

Comment: @marcusshep Question updated.

Comment: You're probably getting the CORS, because you're using nginx and you haven't set CORS for non 200 responses.

Comment: @ElwinArens I searched for the config file of nginx but i found nothing. While i'm search I believe that I found that i'm using wsgi, so I tried to install [wsgicors](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsgicors)  but I was not able to install it because the documentation is not clear enough. Can you please help me?